# Multiple sasl authentication mechanisms in Wildfly 24 with Elytron

Tags: ejb, wildfly, sasl, digest-authentication, elytron

I've set up Wildfly to use OAUTHBEARER auth mechanism for remote JNDI EJB lookups between my server and a desktop app, and it works great.

However, I also want to set up a simple .properties file based auth method to communicate with the server without a token to be able request one, or access information about the keycloak auth server as i don't want to hardcode it into my client application, and I can't seem to make it work. Whatever I do, the server rejects my auth attempts.

The sample code I was trying to reach the a pre auth bean with looks like this:

```
private static PreAuth lookUpPreAuthBean() throws NamingException 
{
    final Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
            
    jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"http-remoting://localhost:8080");
            
    jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "test");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "test");
    
    final Context initialContext = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

    return (PreAuth) initialContext.lookup("ejb:server/server-ejb/PreAuthImpl!co.my.package.server.PreAuth");
}
```

Here is the stacktrace I get:

```
    Suppressed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: ELY05019: No token was given
            at org.wildfly.security.mechanism.oauth2.OAuth2Client.getInitialResponse(OAuth2Client.java:66)
            at org.wildfly.security.sasl.oauth2.OAuth2SaslClient.evaluateMessage(OAuth2SaslClient.java:62)
            at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractSaslParticipant.evaluateMessage(AbstractSaslParticipant.java:225)
            at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractSaslClient.evaluateChallenge(AbstractSaslClient.java:98)
            at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractDelegatingSaslClient.evaluateChallenge(AbstractDelegatingSaslClient.java:54)
            at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.PrivilegedSaslClient.lambda$evaluateChallenge$0(PrivilegedSaslClient.java:55)
            at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.PrivilegedSaslClient.evaluateChallenge(PrivilegedSaslClient.java:55)
            at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.lambda$handleEvent$1(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:459)
            at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(EndpointImpl.java:991)
            at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
            at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        Suppressed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: Server rejected authentication
            at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Authentication.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:760)
            at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Authentication.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:602)
            at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
            at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
            at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
            at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
```

If I was to supply a token, the bearer mechanism works, seems like for some reason the other mechanism is not authenticating

Here are the parts from the Wildfly 24 standalone.xml I've modified:

EJB subsystem:

```
...
<default-security-domain value="other"/>
<application-security-domains>
    <application-security-domain name="other" security-domain="ApplicationDomain"/>
</application-security-domains>
...
```

Elytron subsystem:

- I would like to use the PreAuthRealm for the simple auth.

```
<security-domains>
    <security-domain name="ApplicationDomain" default-realm="JWTRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
        <realm name="JWTRealm" role-decoder="jwt-to-roles"/>
        <realm name="PreAuthRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
    </security-domain>
...
<\security-domains>
```

- I want to use the application-users.properties file to store the username and the password, these credentials were added to the store with the add-user.sh script

```
<security-realms>
    <identity-realm name="local" identity="$local"/>
    <properties-realm name="PreAuthRealm">
        <users-properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="PreAuthRealm"/>
        <groups-properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
    </properties-realm>
    <token-realm name="JWTRealm" principal-claim="*my claim*">
        <jwt issuer="*my issuer*" audience="account">
           <key kid="*my key id*" public-key="*my public key*"/>
        </jwt>
    </token-realm>
</security-realms>
```

- The sasl authentication factory setup:

```
 <sasl-authentication-factory name="application-sasl-authentication" sasl-server-factory="configured" security-domain="ApplicationDomain">
    <mechanism-configuration>
        <mechanism mechanism-name="OAUTHBEARER">
            <mechanism-realm realm-name="JWTRealm"/>
        </mechanism>
        <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST-MD5">
            <mechanism-realm realm-name="PreAuthRealm"/>
        </mechanism>   
    </mechanism-configuration>
</sasl-authentication-factory>
```

Remoting subsystem:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:4.0">
    <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" sasl-authentication-factory="application-sasl-authentication"/>
</subsystem>
```

The strange part is, if I remove the `sasl-authentication-factory="application-sasl-authentication"` from the Remoting subsystem, and put back the original `security-realm="ApplicationRealm"` the above code runs and it actually authenticates me from the .properties file, but then of course the bearer token part won't work, which is the whole point.

What am I missing with my setup here? Is it even possible what i want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but a workaround. Managed to make it work by not naming the realm `"PreAuthRealm"` but naming it the default `"ApplicationRealm"`, and for whatever reason setting this realm as the default realm in the security domain makes this, and the JWT realm, work. Setting the `"JWTRealm"` as default only makes the JWT realm work.